# RecyclerView GridLayout width full width and half width

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-gridview

Is there any way to archieve the following? I want my RecyclerView to be able to display my Cards in a grid of 2 columns, but I also want a couple of cards to have the full screen width, not just the half width. I tried using `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` to archive that, but I cannot find a method to archive that.

**EDIT**
I want the layout to look like this:
[image]

Comment: "I also want a couple of cards to have the full screen width" is *NOT* "i want my recyclerview to be able to display my cards in a grid of 2 columns".
Full-screen sized items are mutually exclusive with your 2 columns idea. Work out what you want and/or draw a picture to illustrate please.

Comment: @Shark sorry if I wasn't clear enough. I added an image to better illustrate it

Comment: Use a combination of layouts? Like grid, with linearlayouts for each non-fullwidth region.

Comment: You can try GridLayout>LinearLayout orientation horizontal>GridLayout /LinearLayout weight 0.5. Not the most efficient implementation probably but it should be possible. I'd give you some sample code if my laptop didn't die on me a few days back...

Comment: @Mingsheng could you give me any code example on how to implement this with recyclerview and layoutmanager?

Comment: oops sorry seems I missed the main point. never really used that before yet. I'll go tinker around a bit tomorrow and see what comes up.

Comment: @Mingsheng thank you very much for your help

Comment: Don't thank me yet I haven't done anything lol. Will reply around this time tomorrow regardless of whether I can get anything out

Comment: aye didn't manage to do much. i will see what i can do.

Answer (score 5):

To expand on shuo Han's answer, say you want a recyclerview with some items spanning full width and others only spanning half width. What you would do is:

```
yourRecyclerView.layoutManager = StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, RecyclerView.VERTICAL)
```

and then inside your adapter, if you want an itemview to span the full width, you write this code in onBindViewHolder:

```
val layoutParams = holder.itemView.layoutParams as StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams
layoutParams.isFullSpan = true
```

Otherwise do not use anything, it will span half way.

Answer (score 1):

```
StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams p = (StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams)holder.itemView.getLayoutParams();
```

`p.setFullSpan()`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) with a [StaggeredGridLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager.html)